# How to handle a large queue (tempfiles?) with multithreading

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

I have written a smart bulkdownloader. My Downloader loads picture urls in a string array. This is locked for multithreading use(One Thread is loading the urls and the other thread is downloading the content behind the urls).

My problem: these long urls needs a lot of ram (we talk about more than 50.000 urls) Are there any alternatives to store them in ram? Maybe with tempfiles? How can i lock them to use the files with multiple threads?

Thanks for your help

Comment: "How can i lock them to use the files with multiple threads?"
what do you want to lock here? files don't need locking to use with multiple threads....

Comment: 50k URLs should be very small (in RAM). Like 50k * 100 bytes = 5MB. You must be storing something else, too, that consumes all that RAM. What could that be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to handle this would be with a transactional database.  Each row in the database would have the URL to retrieve and the filename of the downloaded file.  If the filename is NULL, this means that the file has not been downloaded yet.  If the filename is blank, this means that the file is currently being downloaded.

So, each one of your threads opens a new connection to the database, (because transaction isolation happens per connection,) begins a transaction, finds the first row with a null filename, stores a blank string into the filename, commits the transaction, and starts downloading the file.  Once it is done downloading, it updates the filename.  (No transaction necessary at this time, because no other thread will touch this row, because the row already has a non-null filename.)

Comment: Thank you answering my question so fast. 
I dont know transactional databases. Is this a regular DB like mysql or oracle? or is this a serverless DB?
Do you have time to give me a short example?

Comment: Yes, mysql, oracle, even sqlite all support transactions. I just made sure to mention transactional because there are a few toy databases that do not support transactions, for example tinysql.  SQLite is probably your best bet, you can find info on how to use it in many places, for example here: [The Code Project - Using SQLite in your C# Application](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/22165/Using-SQLite-in-your-C-Application)

Comment: Will i need a SQLite server like for mySQL? My mentor told me this is serverless? If yes, this is my solution!

Comment: Yes, SQLite is serverless, that's why I said it is your best bet.

Comment: Thank you very much!!!! I start the implementation of SQLite in my programm now!

Answer (score 1):

Regardless of anything else, the alternative to memory is files.
That is, if your program consumes too much RAM, just store them in files. Windows and Linux will accelerate usage of recently used files so reading them back would be a lot faster than files you have not touched recently.

The easiest way to handle the files is download to memory, then write to temp file (=final filename + ".t", or some such) in one go, and lastly rename to the final file name.

Other than that, I think your task is bounded more by download speed rather than queue/thread management. Therefore I'd suggest having more threads downloading pictures. I'd try with 1 per cpu, 2 per cpu and so on.
If the pictures come from many different servers, the optimal number of threads would be higher than with a single one.

EDIT:
If the problem is the queue size (very long urls X many of them) I'd go for a single file.
The writer thread can add urls to the file while the reader(s) read them using their own file descriptors.
You can use a long to mark the read position and let every reader atomically increment it when grabbing a url off the queue.
For that the format of the file should include a int url length in frot of the url so a reader should:

1. get current read position, set file position
2. check for end of file, or last write position. skip if at eof.
3. read the url length
4. atomically change read position (CAS) to current + sizeof int + url length
5. if successful, read url

Comment: Mmmm, no.  He would do very well to try with 100 threads.  At any given moment, 99 out of 100 threads will be just sitting there waiting for stuff to arrive from the interwebz.

Comment: The download Speed / the count of Threads are not my problem. I can increase the number of threads for downloading the content with ease. 
I need the solution of this problem to handle other problems late too. 
Can you give me some Advice?

Comment: I don't follow... what is the problem then? the queue?!?! urls are, say, 2KB each, so 2KB*50K = 100MB. This doesn't sound like a big number to me

Comment: I want to keep the application as small as possible (and i want to learn how to use larger queues)